# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage'), cross-origin frame problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I already did my research and I think I'm getting there but I just can't figure out why I keep getting this error.

I have two sites with different DOMAINS which I own, and I will say this that I can insert script on both sides.

Mainwebsite.com contains an iframe from Secondsite.com.

SecondSite.com has a dynamic content which can have a lengthy content and when I load in it in the Mainwebsite.com, I'm getting a scroll problem. Mainwebsite.com should automatically adjust the height of the iframe but I'm having a cross-origin problem.

Here's what I got:

```
Mainwebsite.com

 <script type="text/javascript">
       const frame = document.getElementById('secondSiteContainer');
       frame.postMessage(
          "message",
          "http://secondsite.com",
       );

  frame.postMessage("hello there!", "http://secondsite.com");
  window.addEventListener(
                   "message",
                   (event) => {
                  if (event.origin !== "http://secondsite.com") return;
                            },
                           false,
                   );
 </script>
 <div class="grid grid-col-12" id="secondSiteContainer">
   <iframe src="http://secondsite.com" title="description" width="100%" id="myIframe" style="height: 1700px; border: none;">
    </iframe>
 </div>




secondsite.com

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
        window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        // Do we trust the sender of this message?
          if (event.origin !== "mainsite.com") return;

          event.source.postMessage(
            "hello from 2nd site!",
            event.origin,
      );
        });
    });
```

and now I got the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your object that is calling `postMessage` is not null. It could be null initially for many reasons.

Either try

```
if(frame) {
  frame.postMessage(...)
  ...
}
```

or

```
frame?.postMessage(...)
```